# Drag and Drop Library. Drag Start Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, redips.drag

I am making a chess game in which I have to put a handler on Drag-Start event. I am currently using Redips Library for drag-drop but it doesn't seem to have a Drag-Start event dispatcher. 
I have also tried JQuery UI which support drag but I need specific drop positions (squares of chess) to imitate a move. 
I want to highlight the 'droppable' squares for a move through Drag-Start handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` event for JQuery's draggable UI is documented [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start).

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  start: function( event, ui ) { 
      //code that is to be executed when drag starts 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that with [jQuery UI draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Check out the [snap functionality](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to).